# Trouble with Reset Button Functionality in JavaScript DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a JavaScript project where I have a reset button .again that is supposed to reset the game functionality. However, the code block I have written below doesn't seem to be working as intended

Here is the full code:

```
const secretNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

let score = 20;


document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const guess = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);

    // When there is no input
    if (!guess) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = '❌ No Number';

        // When player win
    } else if (guess === secretNumber) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = '  Correct Number ! ';
        document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#60b347';document.querySelector('.number'),style.width = '30rem'
        document.querySelector('.number').textContent = secretNumber;


    }
    // When guess to high
    else if (guess > secretNumber) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = ' Too High!';
        score--;
        document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;
    }

    
    // guess too low - STUDY ONLY Line 55 annd 56
    else if (guess < secretNumber) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = ' Too Low!';
        score--;
        document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;
    }
    
    // this when you lost
    if (score === 0) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = ' You Lost The Game!';
        
        // STUDY THIS LINE
        document.querySelector('.score').textContent = 0
        
        
    }
});


  document.querySelector('.again').addEventListener('click', function(){
    score = 20;
    secretNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Start Guessing...'
    document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score
    document.querySelector('.number').textContent = '?'
    document.querySelector('.guess').value = '';

    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#222'
    document.querySelector('.number'),style.width = '15rem'
  });
const secretNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

let score = 20;


document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const guess = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);

    // When there is no input
    if (!guess) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = '❌ No Number';

        // When player win
    } else if (guess === secretNumber) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = '  Correct Number ! ';
        document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#60b347';document.querySelector('.number'),style.width = '30rem'
        document.querySelector('.number').textContent = secretNumber;


    }
    // When guess to high
    else if (guess > secretNumber) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = ' Too High!';
        score--;
        document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;
    }

    
    // guess too low - STUDY ONLY Line 55 annd 56
    else if (guess < secretNumber) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = ' Too Low!';
        score--;
        document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;
    }
    
    // this when you lost
    if (score === 0) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = ' You Lost The Game!';
        
        // STUDY THIS LINE
        document.querySelector('.score').textContent = 0
        
        
    }
});


  document.querySelector('.again').addEventListener('click', function(){
    score = 20;
    secretNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Start Guessing...'
    document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score
    document.querySelector('.number').textContent = '?'
    document.querySelector('.guess').value = '';

    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#222'
    document.querySelector('.number'),style.width = '15rem'
  });
```

I have checked for any syntax errors or typos in my code, but I haven't been able to identify the issue. Could someone please review the code and provide some insights into why it might not be functioning as expected?

And am expecting when i guess right or i lose i can press the again button and reset the game.

Comment: Are you sure the code is running? Add a `console.log()` call to it.

Comment: If it's running but not working as intended, what is it doing differently from what you expect?

Comment: "reset" code has no errors, but we don't know how did you initialize the game, what exactly doesn't work when you hit .again?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Your code works (so no syntax errors etc) but we have no idea what "*as intended*" is intended to be!   Here's a fiddle with some implied HTML (as much as needed to show the code working) https://jsfiddle.net/0mu85o4g/  Please [edit] your code and add the *relevant* HTML (not your entire application).

Comment: Please state what you *expect* (or at least wanted) the code to do

Comment: Also. be sure to check the browser console for any errors, eg "cannot set properties of null" means your selectors don't match the HTML

Comment: Your code should be giving `Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable` - as you have `const secretNumber` then try to change it.   That's assuming you don't *actually* have the entire code duplicated, otherwise you'd get the similar `Identifier has already been declared`